# Animating a view when it’s loaded from a nib file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a method that loads a nib file containing a view:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewView" owner:self options:nil];
```

and I was wondering if it's possible to add a simple transition when the view loads. I have scoured the internet and I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863321/iphone-how-to-load-a-view-using-a-nib-file-created-with-interface-builder

Comment: How are you adding the view? That code loads it, but doesn't add it to the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to present views and animate them.

You can create create using loadNibnamed:

[How to load a UIView using a nib file created with Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863321/iphone-how-to-load-a-view-using-a-nib-file-created-with-interface-builder)

One way to animate a view in is to present it modally.  This will animate from the bottom:

```
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

These posts show getting more control how it animates in using modalTransitionStyle

[How can I change the animation style of a modal UIViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237310/how-can-i-change-the-animation-style-of-a-modal-uiviewcontroller)

[iPhone - presentModalViewController with transition from right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876292/iphone-presentmodalviewcontroller-with-transition-from-right)

Another option is to create a view, add it as a subView to your current view and animate the frame.  If you're just loading a view, consider using UINib - it was added in iOS 4.0 and caches.  It double perf.

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TestView" bundle:nil];
UIView *myView = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Then, you can add it as a subView.

If you want to animate subViews within your view, see this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial

Specifically:

```
CGRect basketTopFrame = basketTop.frame;
basketTopFrame.origin.y = -basketTopFrame.size.height;

CGRect basketBottomFrame = basketBottom.frame;
basketBottomFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

basketTop.frame = basketTopFrame;
basketBottom.frame = basketBottomFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```