# Animate presentModalViewController from right /left

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, presentmodalviewcontroller

Currently I am using `[self presentModalViewController :newVC animated:YES]` .I want to present newViewcontroller from left/right/top/bottom with a push effect. I tried to use CATransition but it displays a black screen in between the transition.

Comment: For other people with this problem, I posted the solution I found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876292/iphone-presentmodalviewcontroller-with-transition-from-right/10842991#10842991

Answer (score 91):

When present:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

[self presentModalViewController:viewCtrl animated:NO];
```

When dismiss:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: This seems to be no longer working on iOS 8, as the presenting VC is moving instead of the presented one. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: ¿How I can remove the fading effects?

Comment: What is [tabCtrl release]; at the end of presenting?

Comment: @jalopezsuarez did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: Animations are  very fast... someone knows solve ? [SWIFT]

Comment: @wcrane I am also getting black screen flashing. Actually fadein fadeout and  fadein animation happening. Any hints i am trying to remove the black shade

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Say you want to present a view controller 2 from view controller 1. In the first view controller use

```
 [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: NO]];
```

In the second view controller, in viewWillAppear: method add the code

```
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];

    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];

    [animation setDuration:0.40];
    [animation setTimingFunction:
     [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
      kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];


    [self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];
```

It will work fine. If black screen comes again, if you are using navigation controller, replace

```
   [self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];
```

with

```
   [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];
```

Comment: I also have the black screen problem. Before the modal controller is pushed in a black screen appears. Anyone solved the problem?

Answer (score 3):

After X >= 4 hours of work, this works without "tearing" or other background artifacts:

```
class AboutTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    let presenting: Bool
    let duration: NSTimeInterval

    init(presenting: Bool, duration: NSTimeInterval = 0.25) {
        self.presenting = presenting
        self.duration = duration
    }

    @objc func transitionDuration(ctx: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    @objc func animateTransition(ctx: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let duration = transitionDuration(ctx)
        let containerView = ctx.containerView()
        let fromViewController = ctx.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)!
        let toViewController = ctx.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)!
        let fromView = fromViewController.view // 7.0 & 8.0 compatible vs. viewForKey:
        let toView = toViewController.view     // 7.0 & 8.0 compatible vs. viewForKey:

        containerView.addSubview(fromView)
        containerView.addSubview(toView)

        let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(containerView.frame.width, 0)
        let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-containerView.frame.width, 0)

        fromView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        toView.transform = self.presenting ? offScreenRight : offScreenLeft

        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay:0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions(0), animations: {
            fromView.transform = self.presenting ? offScreenLeft : offScreenRight
            toView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
            ctx.completeTransition(finished)
            if finished {
                fromView.removeFromSuperview()
                fromView.frame = toView.frame // reset the frame for reuse, otherwise frame transforms will accumulate
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Then in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    lazy var window: UIWindow? = {
        return UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    }()

    lazy var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    lazy var nav: UINavigationController = {
        var r = self.storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
        r.delegate = self
        return r
    }()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        self.window!.rootViewController = nav
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        // .. other setup

        return true
    }

    // ...


    // MARK: - UINavigationControllerDelegate

    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        // Example of a SettingsViewController which pushes AboutViewController
        if fromVC is SettingsViewController && toVC is AboutViewController { // Push to About
            return AboutTransition(presenting: true)
        } else if fromVC is AboutViewController && toVC is SettingsViewController { // Pop to Settings
            return AboutTransition(presenting: false)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This assumes an app is using the default storyboard with an initial VC as a `UINavigationController`

Update for swift 3/4

```
class LTRTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning
{ 
let presenting: Bool
let duration: TimeInterval

init(presenting: Bool, duration: TimeInterval = Theme.currentTheme.animationDuration) {
    self.presenting = presenting
    self.duration = duration
}

@objc func transitionDuration(using ctx: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return duration
}

@objc func animateTransition(using ctx: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let duration = transitionDuration(using: ctx)
    let containerView = ctx.containerView
    let fromViewController = ctx.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)!
    let toViewController = ctx.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)!
    guard let fromView = fromViewController.view, // 7.0 & 8.0 compatible vs. viewForKey:
        let toView = toViewController.view     // 7.0 & 8.0 compatible vs. viewForKey:
        else {
            assertionFailure("fix this")
            return
    }
    containerView.addSubview(fromView)
    containerView.addSubview(toView)

    let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransform(translationX: containerView.frame.width, y: 0)
    let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -containerView.frame.width, y: 0)

    fromView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    toView.transform = self.presenting ? offScreenRight : offScreenLeft

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay:0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: 0), animations: {
        fromView.transform = self.presenting ? offScreenLeft : offScreenRight
        toView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
        ctx.completeTransition(finished)
        if finished {
            fromView.removeFromSuperview()
             // this screws up dismissal. at least on ios10 it does               fromView.frame = toView.frame // reset the frame for reuse, otherwise frame transforms will accumulate
        }
    })
}
}
```

And the transitioniningDelegate implementation for the VC being pushed/dismissed:

```
extension WhateverVCyouArePresentingFrom: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
{
public func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
{
    return LTRTransition(presenting: true)
}

public func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
{
    return LTRTransition(presenting: false)
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks tricky, but make it done with just several lines of code.

First, Present LeftSlideViewController modally. You need to specify modalPresentationStyle to .overCurrentContext.

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftSlideViewController") as? LeftSlideViewController {
         vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

And then, Open LeftSlideViewController.

**To move-in from left** (Using CATransition)

- Hide a view in loadView.

  ```
  self.view.isHidden = true
  ```
- Add left-move-in transition animation to a view in viewDidAppear

  ```
  self.view.isHidden = false

  let transition = CATransition.init()
  transition.duration = 0.3
  transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: .easeInEaseOut)
  transition.type = .moveIn
  transition.subtype = .fromLeft

  self.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
  ```

**To move-out to left** (Using UIView animation)

- Animate the view's frame by using UIView's animation and dismiss ViewController when the animation finished

  ```
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
      self.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width * -1, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
  }) { (finished) in
      self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There are only four UIModalTransitionStyles:

```
UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical
UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal
UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve
UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl
```

For example:

```
UIViewController *controller = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UIModalTransitionStyle trans = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: trans forView: [self window] cache: YES];
[navController presentModalViewController: controller animated: NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set a `transitioningDelegate` on the view controller that you want to present.  You must conform to `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` and `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocols.  And by implementing `animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)` you can animate either view controllers subviews.

Function that performs transition

```
class fromViewController : UIViewController {
    let transitionManager = TransitionManager()

    func transitionToViewController() {
      toController.transitioningDelegate = transitionManager
      presentViewController(toController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Then the TransitionManager looks like:

```
import UIKit

class TransitionManager : UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition {
    var presenting = false
}

// MARK: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning
extension TransitionManager : UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let container = transitionContext.containerView()
        let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
        let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!

        let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container.frame.width, 0)
        let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-container.frame.width, 0)

        toView.transform = self.presenting ? offScreenRight : offScreenLeft

        container.addSubview(toView)
        container.addSubview(fromView)
        let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: nil, animations: {
          fromView.transform = self.presenting ? offScreenLeft : offScreenRight
          toView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

          }, completion: { finished in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })
    }


    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 0.3
    }
}


// MARK: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
extension TransitionManager : UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        self.presenting = true
        return self
    }

    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        self.presenting = false
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  The `self.presenting == false` case results in a black screen with the wrong frame

Comment: @Barry This works for me not using segues rather manual transitions between controllers in different storyboards.. By the looks at the code you posted above you are trying to override a push transition of a UINavigationController. Did you have the segue in storyboard set to push rather than present?