# How to achieve pushViewController animation when using presentViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller, ios-animations

I need to use presentViewController in my app -

```
    [self presentViewController:thingContainer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But I need the animation to be similar to that of pushViewController to the navigation controller. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller in the hierarchy?

Comment: @AdamPro13 no I don't

Comment: This looks to be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876292/iphone-presentmodalviewcontroller-with-transition-from-right/10842991#10842991